# return date of max value for a particular id

Tags: mysql, sql, max, aggregate-functions

I want to return date of max value for a particular id. Look at this table.

```
ID       Date       Value 
___      ____       _____
4545     9/17/12    5
4545     9/16/12    100
4545     9/15/12    20
2121     9/16/12    12
2121     9/15/12    132
2121     9/14/12    4
9999     9/16/12    45
9512     9/15/12    128
9512     9/14/12    323
2002     9/17/12    45
```

The results should be:

```
ID       Date       Value 
___      ____       _____ 
4545     9/16/12    100       date for ID(4545) for max value(100)  is "9/16/12"
2121     9/15/12    132       date for ID(2121) for max value1(32)  is "9/15/12"
9999     9/16/12    45        date for ID(9999) for max value(45)   is "9/16/12"
9512     9/14/12    323       -||-
2002     9/17/12    45        -||-
```

How i get this date?

Comment: What platform/language/database?  And what have you tried?  It's hard to reply without details.

Comment: Language sql, database MySQL. I need to copy date of max value for particular id from onne table to another table. I am beginer, so dont know what more do you need to  help me. But thx for help :)

Comment: This is very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464669/return-value-at-max-date-for-a-particular-id) although not an *exact* duplicate because it's taking the max date rather than the max value you are looking for.  But you should be able to adjust the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the set of IDs and their maximum values, then intersect that with your original set.

```
SELECT * FROM t
JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(value) AS value FROM t GROUP BY id) AS max_t
USING (id, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL, you should try something like this (this is MS SQL syntax):

```
SELECT [ID], [Date], [Value]
FROM [YourTable] AS [SRC]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM [YourTable] AS [OTHER]
                  WHERE [OTHER].[ID] = [SRC].[ID] AND [OTHER].[Date] > [SRC].[Date])
```

This is probably not the most efficient way to do this, but it should work...