# How do I cross join the same table with max timestamps per field?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join

Via SQL, I'm trying to get from this:

| id | group_id | session_id | field_label | field_value | sent_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | frosted flakes | blue bowl | first_name | Bob | 2022-11-05 18:18:19.093 |
| 2 | frosted flakes | blue bowl | first_name | Bobby | 2022-11-05 18:17:31.274 |
| 3 | frosted flakes | blue bowl | last_name | Brown | 2022-11-05 18:17:16.241 |
| 4 | frosted flakes | blue bowl | last_name | Browning | 2022-11-05 18:15:34.492 |
| 5 | frosted flakes | blue bowl | last_name | Brownson | 2022-11-05 18:14:58.465 |
| 6 | cheerios | green cup | first_name | Christine | 2022-11-05 18:18:58.222 |
| 7 | cheerios | green cup | last_name | Christmas | 2022-11-05 18:20:41.212 |
| 8 | cheerios | green cup | last_name | Christopherson | 2022-11-05 18:24:58.222 |

where

- `id` is unique
- `group_id` is not unique
- `session_id` is not unique

to this:

| group_id | session_id | amalgamated_field |
| --- | --- | --- |
| frosted flakes | blue bowl | Bob Brown |
| cheerios | green cup | Christine Christopherson |

Where I know the `field_label`s that I want to amalgamate, and I want to get the latest value for each amalgamated field label based on `sent_at` grouped by `group_id`.

So for group **frosted flakes**, I want to get the most recent `field_value` associated with `field_label` **first_name** (Bob) and the most recent `field_value` associated with `field_label` **last_name** (Brown).

And repeat.

I tried a cross join and I also tried an inner join similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464669/return-value-at-max-date-for-a-particular-id).  But I keep getting all combinations :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `ROW_NUMBER` function with conditional aggregation as the following:

```
SELECT group_id, session_id,
       CONCAT_WS(' ', 
                  MAX(CASE WHEN field_label='first_name' AND rn=1 THEN field_value END),
                  MAX(CASE WHEN field_label='last_name' AND rn=1 THEN field_value END)
                ) AS amalgamated_field
FROM
(
  SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group_id, session_id, field_label ORDER BY sent_at DESC) rn
  FROM table_name
) T
GROUP BY group_id, session_id
ORDER BY group_id
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/l_bRreX1).

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres I would recommend `distinct on` and string aggregation:

```
select group_id, session_id, 
    string_agg(field_value, ' ' order by field_label) full_name
from (
    select distinct on (group_id, session_id, field_label) t.*
    from mytable t
    order by group_id, session_id, field_label, sent_at desc
) t
where field_label in ('first_name', 'last_name')
group by group_id, session_id
```

The `distinct on` subquery returns the latest row for each group/session/label tuple. In the outer query, we filter on the two labels we are interested in, and aggregate the field values for each group/session tuple. The `order by` clause of `string_agg` ensures that the first and last name are concatenated in sequence.

Comment: This is a smart and more efficient query, really I liked this solution.

Comment: I think this is ULTIMATELY the most elegant way to accomplish my goal, but I'm currently stuck on a v of postgresql that doesn't support `distinct on` or even `string_agg.`  (Curse you, Redshift.)  We're upgrading this minute, so hope to pull this into the new environment once it's been QA'ed.  In any case, I went with a variant of @ahmed's answer because it was more backwards compatible, but I think this is the "right one"

Answer (score 1):

You can first find the maximum timestamp for each `field_label`, and then perform a self-`join` of the original table back onto the maximum timestamp, aggregating the `field_value`s for each `group_id`:

```
select t1.group_id, t2.session_id, string_agg(t2.field_value,' ') 
from (select t.group_id, t.field_label, max(t.sent_at) d 
   from tbl t group by t.group_id, t.field_label) t1 
join tbl t2 on t1.d = t2.sent_at group by t1.group_id, t2.session_id
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yPhHsEuO).

Comment: Thank you!  This is what I tried to do originally and it didn't QUITE work, but I must've missed something that you captured, because this totally worked, too.